# How can I call a variable from python in R code

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2, read.csv

I'm working in the python environment using rpy2 (using r code in python).

I'm trying to pass a python variable in r while dong read.csv. The python variable holds an array which is shown below:

var is a string in python

```
var =  CAM_4209
```

the command I'm trying to use in  r:

```
 data1 = robjects.r('read.csv("/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_{}.txt".format(var), check.names=FALSE)')
```

However, I keep getting a runtime error.  I'm not sure why this is.

How can I overcome this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated

*************UPDATE*********************
this is the runtime error:

```
    /Users/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Error in (function (file = "", n = NULL, text = NULL, prompt = "?", keep.source = getOption("keep.source"),  : 
  <text>:1:74: unexpected symbol
1: read.csv("/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_{}.txt".format
                                                                             ^

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-4ae8b8e7e4b9> in <module>()
----> 1 data1 = robjects.r('read.csv("/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_{}.txt".format(var), check.names=FALSE)')

/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py in __call__(self, string)
    349 
    350     def __call__(self, string):
--> 351         p = _rparse(text=StrSexpVector((string,)))
    352         res = self.eval(p)
    353         return conversion.ri2py(res)

RRuntimeError: Error in (function (file = "", n = NULL, text = NULL, prompt = "?", keep.source = getOption("keep.source"),  : 
  <text>:1:74: unexpected symbol
1: read.csv("/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_{}.txt".format
```

Comment: Whats the runtime error ? Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @AK47 I pasted the runtime error

Comment: For starters, you are not passing a valid R string. You should use `sprintf` instead of `"".format()`. Or, you could use an `f-string` in python. Something along the lines of `f'read.csv("/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_{var}.txt", check.names=FALSE)'`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik but now when I tried that it's returning the string:"/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_{var}.txt", check.names=FALSE
  It is not reading the file.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik also, if I want to use sprintf should I do the following: 
dataa1 = robjects.r('sprintf("/Users/Downloads/SITES/awFC_"%s".txt, var )'

Comment: @Meow would you happen to know?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to read the csv with R instead of python?  In my case I read data in python then transform as R object in order to run my R function and transform back to python.

Comment: @user32185 Yes, because I assumed it would be more straightforward. read.csv is a one liner in r, vs python which would involve a lengthier code.  In addition, I'm going to need to find out how to import that python variable to r in all cases because I need to run  my Rfunction after that

Comment: Please edit your question and show how the string is evaluated before being passed on to R.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik done. please see above

Comment: @AK47 i posted the stack trace. var is an array

Comment: @hsayya read a csv in Python is one line too. 'pandas.read_csv("file.csv")' then you can activate the auto conversion to R.

Comment: @user32185 Thank you so much. That saved me a lot of time.  But I was just wondering if you could possibly elaborate on what you mean by "activate the auto conversion of R". How can I do that?

Comment: @hsayya have a look at this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/r_interface.html)

Comment: Please note that I prepended the string with 'f'. See [here](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/).